# Can CDI 2.0 be used with weblogic 12c?

Tags: cdi, weblogic12c, java-ee-7, cdi-2.0

I'm using Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 and I would like to know if I can use CDI 2.0.
My beans.xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all" version="2.0">
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weblogic 12c appears to be JavaEE 7, so you'd be on CDI 1.2. It's unlikely there's a way to substitute the CDI implementation.

Comment: Per https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES309 Weblogic 12c supports CDI 1.1